# Is having a parent controller to manage a set of tabbed sections an anti-pattern for an angular application?

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, anti-patterns, angularjs

A lot of times, I have long forms that I divide into multiple tabbed sections. Each section is managed by it's own controller and there is a parent controller that manages the whole view. I use ui-router for dividing such sections into states.

Should I make a service instead of a controller to manage the all the sections but generally, I don't have business logic in their. It's mostly done for collection data altogether and passing  it to an API using ng-resource.

I know

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for a parent controller. If your tabbed panel behavior is general enough, you might consider abstracting it further into a directive. But generally there is nothing wrong with creating a top-level controller to coordinate several related child controllers.